# Cannot find RowClickEventArgs in DevexpressGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm a new to `DevexpressGridView`.

I have a Dev Grid in my webpage, and I want to handle the `RowClick Event` like:

```
private void GridView1_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e)
{
    if(a row is selected)// how???
        Button1.Visible=true;
}
```

But when it has an error: `"cannot resolve symbol RowClickEventArgs"`, this is first time I know about Devexpress. So I wonder if my `RowClickEventArgs` syntax is wrong??? I've tried to find the solution by searching google for many times, but I still cannot get the right thing.

Can you give me a right syntax???

And one more question, how can I check `" is there any row selected ?"`

Help!

Answer (score -1):

So it would be like this:

```
private void GridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.DataRow row = GridView2.GetDataRow(GridView2.FocusedRowHandle);
    if(row[0].ToString() == "")
    {
          //YOUR LOGIC
    }

}
```

GridView2 is your main view.

Comment: Can you tell me more? I just use only one Grid in my webpage,what is exactly GridView2?

Comment: I thought you are using windows form application, in your case I suggest you take a look at this example, I hope it helps.  http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/546734/DevExpressplusgridcontrolplushowplusweplusgetpluss