# Cannot resolve symbol RowClickEventArgs

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a DevexpressGridView  in my webpage.

I have a Dev Grid in my webpage, and I want to handle the `RowClick Event` like:

```
   private void GridView1_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if(a row is selected)// how???
            Button1.Visible=true;
    }
```

But it seems RowClickEventArgs doesn't exist, it has an error: `"cannot resolve symbol RowClickEventArgs"`, this is first time I know about Devexpress. So I wonder if my `RowClickEventArgs` syntax is wrong???

I've tried to find the solution by searching google for many times, but I still cannot get the right thing.

Help!!!

Comment: You asked this question earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217076/cannot-find-rowclickeventargs-in-devexpressgridview - why are you asking it again? -1 for adding unnecessary noise to SO.

Comment: sorry for my impolite, but I really need the solution right now, but the old question has no right answer, and it seems nobody can read it again. Poor me!

Comment: Why do not contact [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) guys directly?

Answer (score 1):

There is no RowClickEventArgs in DevExpress ASPxGridView as far as the RowClick server event. Do you mean the [ASPxClientGridViewRowClickEventArgs](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridViewRowClickEventArgstopic)?

I believe, you should read more about the DevExpress ASPxGridView concepts related to selection from the corresponding help topic: [Selection](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3737)

Related example (obtaining selection): [How to delete the ASPxGridView's selected rows](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3076)